# Optimizing code solution for Palindrome Index-Hackerrank

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, palindrome

I submitted my solution for palindrome Index coding challenge but I get "test cases terminated due to time out error". My code is working and so I don't know what else to do to optimize it. Please help:

```
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    let palindrome = s === s.split('').reverse().join('')
    if(!palindrome) {
        let i = 0
        let integerIndex = []
        let arr = s.split('')
        while(i < s.length) {
            arr.splice(i,1)
            if(arr.join('') === arr.reverse().join('')) {
               integerIndex.push(i) 
            }
            arr = s.split('')
            i++
        }
        return integerIndex.length > 0 ? integerIndex[0] : - 1
    }else {
        return -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the text of the question and a link to the coding challenge to the body of this question? We need the exact specification of the coding challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may well be an error @ [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/problem). If I'm not mistaken the nodejs-code expects you to provide console input. Or you may have accidentally changed something in the surrounding code.

Concerning your code: writing ES20xx, it's good practice to terminate lines with a semicolon (`;`), because not doing so may result in [nasty bugs](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/codebyte-why-are-explicit-semicolons-important-in-javascript-49550bea0b82/).

> `let palindrome = s === s.split('').reverse().join('')`

You don't need this variable. It could've been:

`if(s !== s.split('').reverse().join('')) {`

Furthermore, if you wanted to declare a variable, it could've been a `const` here (you are not modifying it afterwards).

Just for fun, here's an alternative approach, using substrings from the original given string:

```js
"hannach,ava,reopaper,annana,ewve,blob,otto,michael,racecaar,wasitacatiwsaw"
  .split(",")
  .forEach(name => console.log(`[${name}] => ${palindromeIndex(name)}`));
  
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    if (`${[...s]}` === `${[...s].reverse()}`) { return "is palindrome"; }
    let i = 0;
    while(i < s.length) {
      const sx = `${i < 1 ? s.substr(1, 0) : s.substr(0, i)}${s.substr(i + 1)}`; 
      const  rsx = `${[...sx].reverse().join("")}`;
      if (sx === rsx) {
        return `removing '${s[i]}' (@ position ${i}): '${sx}'`;
      };
      i += 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```